# Align equation insert huge spaces

Tags: align, amsmath

I want to write a set of equations in LaTeX, but I'd like the signs `=` and the texts `in` to be aligned. Hence I use the `align` environment.

```tex
\begin{align}
    -2\mu \nabla\cdot(D(u)) + \nabla p &= \rho f &\text{in }\Omega,\\
    \nabla\cdot u &= 0 &\text{in }\Omega,
\end{align}
```

All the texts are indeed aligned with this code, but a huge space is present between the second and third columns:

[image]

If I understand the [documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/amsldoc.pdf/0#section.3.6) well, this is because it groups the texts two by two, and in my case, as I have three columns, the third one is displayed at the very right of the page.

I could fix this using a `tabular`, but I'd lose the numbering of the equations:

```tex
\begin{tabular}{rcll}
    $-2\mu \nabla\cdot(D(u)) + \nabla p$ &$=$ & $\rho f$ &in $\Omega$,\\
    $\nabla\cdot u$ & $=$ & $0$ & in $\Omega$,
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Is there a workaround to do it with `align`?

Comment: Mantra: when you use more than one alignment point, you need 2x(num alignment points)+1 number of `&` per line. Here you need 3 and you only have 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you employ an `alignat` environment instead of an `align` environment, as the former permits finer control over spacing. Fo instance, in the code shown below, I set the amount of whitspace to the left of `\text{in $\Omega$}` to `\quad`. Observe that `alignat` takes a mandatory argument: the number of (implicit) columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' and 'alignat' environments

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    -2\mu \nabla\cdot(D(u)) + \nabla p 
        &= \rho f &\text{in }\Omega,\\
    \nabla\cdot u 
        &= 0 &\text{in }\Omega,
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    -2\mu \nabla\cdot(D(u)) + \nabla p 
        &= \rho f &\quad&\text{in $\Omega$},\\
    \nabla\cdot u 
        &= 0      &&     \text{in $\Omega$},
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know the existence of this environment, the result is correct with it, thanks